# Recover an HFS+ formatted IDE drive connected via USB-IDE adapter

Tags: macos, usb, data-recovery, pata, testdisk

I have a 120GB IDE drive connected to my MacBook via a IDE-USB adapter. I formatted it fresh with a single full-size HFS+ partition and backed up a bunch of stuff.

Unfortunately, upon reconnecting the drive to my MacBook, the drive showed up as unrecognized, and in the Disk Utility the disk shows up as a different capacity than it actually is. To make matters worse, it seems to come up with a different size each time I reconnect it.

I have poked around with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), and it's accompanying PhotoRec, but have been a little paranoid to make any changes.  PhotoRec kept failing because it would not detect the drive size correctly. Are there any other worthwhile non-destructive options?

Given I know the actual drive size, should I be able to recover the partition by manually resetting the partition table? Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I know TestDisk can do this, but given that it doesn't detect the correct drive capacity, I've been very hesitant to make any changes as I do not want to lose this data if I can help it.

Comment: Have you made progress with this problem? The question was bumped to the front page today.

Comment: Took a while to recover my old desktop, but I finally had some success. With the disk connected directly to the motherboard IDE port, and the desktop running Linux, I was able to recover 95% of the data on my desk with photorec. It ran for about 3 straight days, and completed happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another USB-IDE adapter.

Comment: I have tried two, two different brands, same result. Go figure.

Comment: The only other suggestion is connect it directly to PC motherboard with IDE, if you have one. How important is the data?

Comment: I'd be disappointed if I lost the data, but it won't ruin my life. :)

I had not thought of that. I will have to locate a system with an IDE port, as I retired my desktop a long time ago.

Comment: Moab, as I mentioned in the comment above, using the onboard IDE port, instead of a IDE adapter, the disk behaved a lot better, and managed to finish a photorec scan. Thanks for the suggestion!